# Static method only recognizes one object and no others

Tags: java

I have been working on this program and have recently came to an error using a static method.
I don't normally use static methods but they are in the requirements.

So i have a static method VerifyUserNameAndPassWord which takes an input of a list of users and a user name and password and compares it to the ones stored in the object to see if the details are correct.

Unfortunately with this method it only ever recognized "User1" (Thefirst object) and any time i try to put in user2's username and password it always throws the illegal argument error i put in.

User 2 is stored in the array list of course.

This is my main method:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your user name");
        String userName = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter your password name");
        String passWord = scanner.nextLine();


        if(User.verifyLoginByUsernameAndPassword(userList, userName, passWord)== true)

        {
          do something..
        }
```

And this is the static method:

```
public static boolean verifyLoginByUsernameAndPassword(ArrayList<User> user, String username, String password)
{
    boolean check = false;
    for(User s: user)
    {
        if(username.equals(s.getUserName()) && password.equals(s.getPassWord()))
        {
            check = true;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            check = false;
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Username and password are incorrect ");

        }
    }
    return check;

}
```

Comment: You need to not throw the exception until you've processed the entire array and `check` is still false. At the moment you're throwing it on the first mismatch. `static` has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your method implementation. Check the entire list then throw exception if username and passwords not matched.

```
public static boolean verifyLoginByUsernameAndPassword(ArrayList<User> user, String username, String password) {
    for(User s: user) {
        if(username.equals(s.getUserName()) && password.equals(s.getPassWord())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Username and password are incorrect ");

}
```